# performance information and tools say thst mt computer is 64-bit capable but system information says it is not

Tags: windows-7

I checked my system type on system information , and it said CPU is not 64-bit capable.
But I checked my system type on performace information and tools , and it said CPU is 64-bit capable.

Comment: Have you tried CPU-Z ? Trusted by many used by millions https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: Try this utility, it does not lie.........https://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Answer (score 0):

When running 32 bit Windows the "System Type" field in the System Information utility will always identify as "X86-based PC", even with the latest computers which are fully 64 bit capable. And for most practical purposes that is what it is. This was not intended to show 64 bit capability.

A CPU capable of running 64 bit Windows has 2 modes, 32 bit mode and 64 bit mode. To run 32 bit Windows it must be in 32 bit mode. In this mode it is for all practical purposes a 32 bit CPU with all 64 bit capabilities locked out. The CPU will even identify itself as 32 bit. Software must do some very specific things to reveal the CPUs 64 bit capabilities. CPU-Z and other utilities do this. Only when running a 64 bit OS is it's true nature revealed.

This is all done for compatibility reasons. There is much older 32 bit software that was written before the availability of 64 bit operating systems and has zero 64 bit awareness. Such software may behave badly or fail entirely if the OS or CPU were to identify itself as anything other than 32 bit. Even in a 64 bit OS 32 bit software will see it as a 32 bit OS.

Windows Control Panel in a 32 bit OS may identify the CPU as 64 bit capable but this isn't always the case, at least in Windows 7. I have an old computer that when running 32 bit Windows 7 there was no indication of 64 bit capability. Other 32 bit Windows 7 systems do show this. But the computer was fully 64 bit capable, having run a 64 bit OS in a virtual machine and in dual boot. Windows 10 does show 64 bit capability.

CPU-Z and other utilities will reliably show 64 bit capability.